# how to check inputs value to find if a char exists more than x times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Validating an input with js or jquery, I need to be able to display error message if this input's value contains this character '&' more than once, twice or whatever times I want. Is there a simple or effective way to do this with js?

```
            var name = $('input').val();
            if (name.length < 2 || name== "&&" ) {
                this.mensajeria("invalid search \n");
                return false;
                console.log("something went wrong");
            }else{
                console.log("everything it's ok");
            }
```

this input is being used for names of natural persons or companies, so that is why I need to allow that user inserts '&' but it can't be many of them.

Comment: Please share the code you are working with, along with what you've tried and what results you've had so far.

Comment: Regular expressions.

Comment: I just edited the post

Comment: `if (name.split('&').length - 1 >= 1)`

Comment: could you describe please how this operate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```js
$(function(){
 check();
 $('input').on('change keyup keydown',function(){
  check();  
 });  
});
function check(){
 var name = $('input').val();
 if(name.replace(/[^&]+/g,'').length > 1){
  console.log("something went wrong");
  return false;
 }else{
   console.log("everything it's ok");
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="abc && as &"/>
```

Comment: this fits perfect with what I'm looking for, you figured it out, thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

Try using Sting.match

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

```js
$('#submitMyTextBox').click(function() {
  var str = $('#myTextBox').val();
  var regexp = /[\&]/gi;
  var matches_array = [];
  var count = 0;
  var message = "";

  matches_array = str.match(regexp);
  matches_array === null ? count = 0 : count = matches_array.length;
  count > 1 ? message = "More than 1 '&'' found." : message = "everything it's ok";

  $('#message').html(message);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myTextBox">
<button id="submitMyTextBox">Submit</button>

<div id="message"></div>
```